# What is wrong with this ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%[ Var @xml, @objects, @object, @rows

Set @xml = '<root>
<object>
<headline>
headline
</headline>
</object>
<object>
<headline>
headline
</headline>
</object>
</root>'

Set @objects = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//root/object/headline",1)

SET @rows = RowCount(@objects)
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do 
Set @object = Field(Row(@objects,@cnt), "Value")

]%%
%%=v(@object)=%%

%%[next @cnt]%%
```

No errors display and nothing else displays

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be working as-is.

I added a couple of things for verification:

```
%%[

Var @xml, @objects, @object, @rows

Set @xml = '<root>
<object>
<headline>
headline
</headline>
</object>
<object>
<headline>
headline
</headline>
</object>
</root>'

Set @objects = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//root/object/headline",1)

SET @rows = RowCount(@objects)
outputline(concat("<br>rows: ",@rows))
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
  Set @object = Field(Row(@objects,@cnt), "Value")
  outputline(concat("<br>",@cnt, ": object: ",@object))
next @cnt

]%%
```

**Output**

```
rows: 2 
1: object: headline 
2: object: headline
```